# LINUX -- DMA for data transfer -- read from SPI --- tx to usart - RPi

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi, dma

How DMA actually works is theory which i knows ;--
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access

But in programming how we have to manage it  ?

I am using RPI & looking forward to implement following operation using DMA.
Suppose if i want to read from SD card using SPI ---- TX read data --- to USART.

Do i have to write routine for data transfer & give them to dma or it is handles by DMA tx & rx channels ?

What linux internals to be used for it ?

Can some expert tell what steps to follow in this regard. I am new to DMA programming.lin

Comment: *"read from SD ... to USART"* - Buffering data in main memory is the norm, for DMA or PIO.  Device-to-device transfers are rarely performed, and simply not possible with typical hardware.  The "M" in DMA is for "memory", so DMA controllers transfer between devices and to/from memory.  And some DMA controllers also do mem-to-mem xfers.  The SPI and USART drivers probably already use DMA.  Are you going to rewrite the SPI and USART drivers?

Comment: +1. This is a real question. There is in fact a conflict between SPI and UART transfers on most ARM designs. See http://dics.voicecontrol.ro/process_mails/arata_discutia/139618/DMA_Corrupts_UART_RX.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check Raspberrypi SoC hardware spec. 
http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf

Broadcom DMA support SPI TX/RX and SD Host Interface. It means it can support device to memory at least (I am not sure that does broadcom SoC support device to device DMA).

Different SoC has different DMA configure way. 
For example, it only needs to assign source address, increment/decrement(length), destination address, increment/decrement(length), counter and interrupt on some simply DMA engine. 
When finished a DMA transfer, it will trigger a interrupt.

roughly review Broadcom's SoC. 
It has other options, ex: WAITS, PERMAP. 
I am not Broadcom SoC expert, maybe you can use default value to configure it.